# XML to data frame with missing nodes

Tags: xml, r, dataframe, xml2

Versions of this question have been asked before, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335596/parse-xml-with-getnodeset-identify-missing-tags) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985218/xml-to-dataframe-how-to-get-a-default-value-if-node-does-not-exist). However, I still can't get it to work. I'm trying to parse an XML document into a data frame. The problem is that the some of the variables are not present for some of the observations, so I'm getting an error because there are a different number of rows. My data looks like this:

```
library("xml2")
library("dplyr")

example <- read_xml(
'
<particDesc>
<person role="participant" sameAs="#P484" xml:id="EDcon250_S1">
<age value="3">35-49</age>
<sex value="1">male</sex>
<occupation>waiter</occupation>
<langKnowledge>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="ita"/>
</langKnowledge>
</person>
<person role="participant" sameAs="#P485" xml:id="EDcon250_S7">
<age value="0">unknown</age>
<sex value="2">female</sex>
<occupation>waitress</occupation>
<langKnowledge>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
</langKnowledge>
</person>
<person role="participant" sameAs="#P465" xml:id="EDcon250_S2">
<age value="2">25-34</age>
<sex value="2">female</sex>
<langKnowledge>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="eng-US"/>
</langKnowledge>
</person>
</particDesc>
')
```

I'm using Wickham's `xml2` package to read the xml. I would prefer using this package, but would be open to using `XML` if that is the best (or only) way of solving this problem. Anyways, my code is the following:

```
participants <- xml_find_all(example, './/person[@role = "participant"]')

extract_participants <- function(div){
id <- xml_attr(div, "id")
same_as <- xml_attr(div, "sameAs")
role <- xml_attr(div, "role")
age <- xml_find_all(div, ".//age") %>% xml_text()
sex <- xml_find_all(div, ".//sex") %>% xml_text()
occupation <- xml_find_all(div, ".//occupation") %>% xml_text()

data_frame(id, same_as,role, age, sex, occupation)
}


parts_ls <- lapply(participants, extract_participants)

participants_df <- do.call(rbind, parts_ls)
```

The problem in this specific concerns the `occupation` variable (the third person doesn't have one), but in my actual data it could be one of the other variables as well. As I said, I can see that this question has been asked before, but I could get any of the suggestions to work (probably due to my not completing understanding the solution). Ultimately, I would like NAs to be returned whenever a particular node is missing (so the `occupation` variable for the third person would be `NA`.

On edit: 
Here's the alternative `XML` version

```
library("XML")
library("magrittr")

example2 <- xmlParse(
'
 <particDesc>
 <person role="participant" sameAs="#P484" xml:id="EDcon250_S1">
 <age value="3">35-49</age>
 <sex value="1">male</sex>
 <occupation>waiter</occupation>
 <langKnowledge>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="ita"/>
 </langKnowledge>
 </person>
 <person role="participant" sameAs="#P485" xml:id="EDcon250_S7">
 <age value="0">unknown</age>
 <sex value="2">female</sex>
 <occupation>waitress</occupation>
 <langKnowledge>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
 </langKnowledge>
 </person>
 <person role="participant" sameAs="#P465" xml:id="EDcon250_S2">
 <age value="2">25-34</age>
 <sex value="2">female</sex>
 <langKnowledge>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="eng-US"/>
 </langKnowledge>
 </person>
 </particDesc>
')

example_root <- xmlRoot(example2) 

process <- function(x){
id <- xmlGetAttr(x, "id")
role <- xmlGetAttr(x, "role")
age <- getNodeSet(x, ".//age") %>% xmlSApply(xmlValue)
sex <- getNodeSet(x, ".//sex") %>% xmlSApply(xmlValue)
#occupation <- getNodeSet(x, ".//occupation") %>% xmlSApply(xmlValue)
data.frame(id = id,
           role = role,
           #occupation = occupation,
           age = age,
           sex = sex,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}


 ls <- xpathApply(example_root, "//person", process)
 df <- do.call(rbind, ls)
```

Just uncomment `occupation` to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got something to work, but I'm not sure whether it is an ideal solution (I think it is pretty long-winded). Anyways, here is what I have so far. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```
library("XML")
library("magrittr")

example2 <- xmlParse(
'
<particDesc>
<person role="participant" sameAs="#P484" xml:id="EDcon250_S1">
<age value="3">35-49</age>
<sex value="1">male</sex>
<occupation>waiter</occupation>
<langKnowledge>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="ita"/>
</langKnowledge>
</person>
<person role="participant" sameAs="#P485" xml:id="EDcon250_S7">
<age value="0">unknown</age>
<sex value="2">female</sex>
<occupation>waitress</occupation>
<langKnowledge>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
</langKnowledge>
</person>
<person role="participant" sameAs="#P465" xml:id="EDcon250_S2">
<age value="2">25-34</age>
<sex value="2">female</sex>
<langKnowledge>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
<langKnown level="L1" tag="eng-US"/>
</langKnowledge>
</person>
</particDesc>
')

example_root <- xmlRoot(example2) 
person <- getNodeSet(example_root, "//person")

id <- lapply(person, xmlGetAttr, "id") %>% unlist()
role <- lapply(person, xmlGetAttr, "role") %>% unlist()
age <- lapply(person, xpathSApply, ".//age", xmlValue) %>% unlist()
sex <- lapply(person, xpathSApply, ".//sex", xmlValue) %>% unlist()
occupation <- lapply(person, xpathSApply, ".//occupation", xmlValue)
occupation[sapply(occupation, is.list)] <- NA 
occupation <- unlist(occupation)

df <- data.frame(
   id = id,
   role = role,
   age = age,
   sex = sex,
   occupation = occupation)
```

On Edit: 
For completion, here is the corresponding `xml2` version (abridged)

```
example <- read_xml(
'
 <particDesc>
 <person role="participant" sameAs="#P484" xml:id="EDcon250_S1">
 <age value="3">35-49</age>
 <sex value="1">male</sex>
 <occupation>waiter</occupation>
 <langKnowledge>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="ita"/>
 </langKnowledge>
 </person>
 <person role="participant" sameAs="#P485" xml:id="EDcon250_S7">
 <age value="0">unknown</age>
 <sex value="2">female</sex>
 <occupation>waitress</occupation>
 <langKnowledge>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
 </langKnowledge>
 </person>
 <person role="participant" sameAs="#P465" xml:id="EDcon250_S2">
 <age value="2">25-34</age>
 <sex value="2">female</sex>
 <langKnowledge>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="ger-AT"/>
 <langKnown level="L1" tag="eng-US"/>
 </langKnowledge>
 </person>
 </particDesc>
')

participants <- xml_find_all(example, './/person[@role = "participant"]')

id <- lapply(participants, xml_attr, "id")
occupation <- lapply(participants, xml_find_all, ".//occupation")
occupation <- lapply(occupation, xml_text)
occupation[!sapply(occupation, function(y) length(y == 0))] <- NA

occupation <- unlist(occupation)
id <- unlist(id)

data_frame(
  id = id, 
  occupation = occupation)
```